# What does the exclamation mark mean in an Objective-C if statement?

Tags: objective-c, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I am wondering what the exclamation mark in `if(!anObject)` means.

Comment: `!` is the logical `NOT` unary operator. I urge you to read an introductory book on Objective C before trying to write actual code.

Comment: This really isn't about Objective C, but pretty much all programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, Paul! I am reading on Objective C and only do some code to memorize some stuff. It actually helps.

Comment: And that's what I thought actually - that ! is a NOT operator, but how come that when I leave the first if only it actually DOES add the operands when it shouldn't?

Comment: Because your logic is backwards.

Answer (score 11):

It is the boolean NOT operator also called negation.

```
!true == false;
!false == true;
```

Comment: yeah, but if you leave just this    if (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"+"]) {
        int sum=a+b;
        [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];
        
    } it actually does add the numbers. WHen from what I understand it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

That is the [Logical NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator, i.e., `if( thisThisIsNotTrue ) { doStuff }`.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I thought actually - that ! is a NOT operator, but how come that when I leave the first "if" part only it actually DOES add the operands when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

It's a C operator, simply meaning "not". So !YES == NO and !NO == YES are both true statements. `if (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"+"])`, for example, checks to see if txtOperator.text is NOT equal to @"+".

Comment: as I wrote in the comments earlier, it actually does add with the NOT operator when it is not supposed to.

Comment: As the comments above point out, your logic is "backwards". `if(!thisValueIsFalse) {
//code here will execute
}`  So your first `if` statement will only execute if `txtOperator.text` is NOT (!) @"+", obviously not the correct behavior.  The !'s aren't needed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If it always adds, then your string is never "+".

The logic as you have it will always add a+b unless the txtOperator.txt is exactly equal to @"+".

Interestingly if you did pass a plus it would always subtract, only the first two cases would ever be hit because if the first was not true the second always would be.

Basically, take out all the "!"....

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has mention is just a NOT operator, what I believe might have confused you is the brackets [], Objective C, comes from a language called small talk, that uses a send message approach to objects, the brackets are used to send that message. The messages are really functions.

Comment: the brackets are actually more or less clear, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should not add "!" to the start of condition in "if". Your code says that if operator's text is not +, then add and so on. Your code should be like this;

-(IBAction) calculateResult {

```
a = [txtOperand1.text intValue];
b = [txtOperand2.text intValue];

if ([txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"+"]) {
    int sum=a+b;
    [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];

} else if ([txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"-"]) {
    int sum=a-b;
    [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];
}
else if  ([txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"/"]) {
    int sum=a/b;
    [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];

}
else if  ([txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"*"]) {
    int sum=a * b;
    [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];


}
else [result setText:@"nothing"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So what about its use in a statement like this (taken from an online class example):

*(In this example, a button is pressed and upon clicking the button, the code below "toggles" between the Default state and the Selected state):*

```
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, after I read Apple's documentation, isSelected returns a BOOL, so it is equivalent to say: