# why a line with logical NOT still does what a YES would do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the exclamation mark in Objective C means in “if (![”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576413/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-in-objective-c-means-in-if)

in my previous question I wasn't quite clear. What puzzles me is why in this line:

```
   if (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"+"]) {
        int sum=a+b;
        [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];

    }
```

the operands are added and result displayed even though with the NOT operator it was not supposed to happen and when I add the following lines the calculator continues to do addition only doesn't matter what operator you put there.

```
else if (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"-"]) {
        int sum=a-b;
        [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];
    }
    else if  (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"/"]) {
        int sum=a/b;
        [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];

    }
    else if  (![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"*"]) {
        int sum=a * b;
        [result setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum]];


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have those `!` in the first place? `isEqualToString` returns `YES` if the strings are equal and `NO` otherwise. If the operand is not `@"+"`, why would you want to make additions?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)?

Comment: @CalT seriously? You are posting a comment to a six year old question?!!

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at what you're doing in detail here:

```
[txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"-"]
```

You are checking if the `txtOperator.text` equals @"-".

So if it is `-`, it will return `YES`.

Otherwise `NO`.

Then you negate this statement:

```
![txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"-"]
```

Now everything that is NOT a `-` will return `YES`.

And only the `-` will return `NO`.

Thus in your example, the if-clause is entered in every case **but** when the string matches. To check for string matches, leave out the NOT operator.

Comment: I removed ! everywhere, now it doesn't match any conditions :( How do I check if user enters "+" in the operator field?

Comment: The quick way to test would be putting an NSLog statement right before the call to see what `txtOperator.text` actually contains as such: `NSLog(@"%@",txtOperator.text);`

Comment: Upvoted so you get your 1k :-)

Comment: @Sidyll -> Time to open that bottle of champagne I have in the basement. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some magick:

```
    NSString * a = nil;
    if (![a isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
    NSLog(@"A");
    }
    if (![a isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
    NSLog(@"B");
    }
```

Output:

```
    A
    B
```

Clear enough ? Be careful sending messages to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Try imagining what will happen in your code. Say your operator is `@"-"`. Now, on the first test

```
[txtOperator.text isEqualToString: @"+"]
```

Will return `NO`. But then, you negate this (`!`) so it becomes `YES` and your if condition succeeds.

If your operator is whatever thing (except `@"+"`) it will always succeed on the first test. Now, if it's a `@"+"`, the second test will succeed. Can you imagine why?

Comment: the problem is that with @"+" it succeeds the first time as well :)

Comment: @SergeyE: Hmm, I don't think so. Check if it's really a `@"+"`, and not a `@"+ "` or something like. The problem might be somewhere else tough.